Service Principal in Azure cannot create DevBox in azure portals
service principal account cannot use az cli to create a devbox.
ERROR: (DevBoxCreationByApplicationNotSupported) Dev Box creation is only supported for users.
anyone have any solution to this
my code is using az cli commands and the service principal is owner for the subscription.
az login --service-principal -u $ACCESS_KEY -p $SECRET_KEY --tenant var{tenant_id}
# Check if Dev Box exists
DEV_BOX_EXISTS=$(az devcenter dev dev-box list --dev-center-name $DEV_CENTER_NAME --query "[?name=='$DEV_BOX_NAME'] | length(@)")
# Create Dev Box
if [ "$DEV_BOX_EXISTS" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Dev Box $DEV_BOX_NAME does not exist. Creating Dev Box..."
    az devcenter dev dev-box create  \
  --pool-name $POOL_NAME \
  --name $DEV_BOX_NAME \
  --dev-center-name $DEV_CENTER_NAME \
  --project-name $PROJECT_NAME 



Service Principal in Azure cannot create DevBox in azure portal.

According to this Github issue by dbradish-microsoft.

It seems that Dev Box creation is only supported for users, not for service principals. Therefore, you cannot use the service principal account to create a Dev Box using the Azure CLI.

As of now, the only possible way to create the devbox supported for users only using this MS-Document.
In the above github issue there is already link to submit the feature request for creating a dev box with service principal.
